# Nestjs cant connect to mongoDB on raspberry pi

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, nestjs

the mongoDB service starts up nicely. Even in the console are no errors when I start it with `mongo`. But if I try to serve my nestjs application I get this error: 
`[Nest] 3922   - 03/28/2020, 13:41:08   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +62ms`.
My Module looks like this:

```
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    // Mongoose
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/api', { useNewUrlParser: true }),

    // Custom Modules
    UserModule,
    MovieModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tested it on my Laptop, OS: Ubuntu. The application works fine.
So I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Is your rasp pi located in the same network? You could try to check the connection with a Mongo shell.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a network and/or config issue. Is the target MongoDB server is running on the Raspberry PI? If not, you must adapt its [Bind IP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/) so you can connect from an other device of the local network.

Comment: thanks for the responds. yes mongoDB is
running as a service on localhost on my raspberry pi. my /etc/mongodb.conf looks like this. ```# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true
```
if I start the application on my ubuntu laptop, everything is fine.

Comment: Dit you ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue at the moment.

Comment: nope, sorry. There must be a resolving issue here. If I want to run node applications, I don't have any problems with my localhost...